# Calculating share of overlapping areas via aggregate function in a virtual field

Tags: qgis, sql, qgis-3, intersection, statistics

I'm trying to calculate the shared area for several overlapping areas. I need a dynamic solution in order to get automatically calculated statistics when drawing new polygons.

[image]

The target area is in this case the layer which contains the zoning plans. The other layer specifies the type of landuse (Markanvändning). The ultimate goal is to have a virtual field in the zoning layer, which grabs the information from the landuse-layer to define the share of different landuse-types (area) within the plan.

```
((aggregate(layer:='Markanvändning_e90475ff_88be_43f2_8eae_b14419c74d08', aggregate:='sum', expression:= (area(intersection($geometry, geometry(@parent)))), concatenator:=',',  filter:= "kategori" IS 'Offentlig'))/ "area_DP")*100
```

My approach was to create a virtual field within the zoning plan layer with an aggregate function, which calculates the share with the help of an intersect function. I created a test-layer and everything works fine if I just have one zoning-plan, but when I draw several plans I just get a result for the first row in my zoning plan layer.

[image]

What is going wrong here?

Comment: I don't see any obvious mistakes in that expression. Just to rule out one possibility:  Are you sure that "Andel_Privat" and "Andel_Offentlig" are actually virtual fields? Because if you already had the first feature when you created these fields, and forgot to check the "virtual field" box, then you would have calculated values for the first feature, and *NULL* values any features you create later.

Comment: Yes I checked that, both are virtual fields. When I try to use to code as a standard expression in the field calculator I get this error message: _"Couldn't calculate aggregation for: area(intersection($geometry, geometry(var('parent'))))"_! If I just select the first row in the attribute table and try to use the code it works totally fine!

Comment: Why do you think the error message has `geometry(var('parent))`? The expression in your question has it as `geometry(@parent)`.

Comment: Actually I have no idea why it shows me the error message like that! I think it is basically the same just with a different style of expression. Tested it with the expression in the error message and I get the same result for the first row!

Comment: I got a variation of your expression to work a couple times, but then I started getting the same error message. I think this is a bug.

Comment: In case this helps, here's the expression that worked (but it doesn't anymore): `aggregate('landuse', 'sum', area(intersection($geometry, geometry(@parent))), "kategori" = 'Offentlig' )`. I took out the concatenator because I couldn't figure out when you would need it. Isn't a sum always a single value?

Comment: I supposed that it could be a bug but I wasn't sure! I tested your code now but unfortunately I have the same issues as before. How did you solve the problem in the end? Another code or a completely different approach?

Comment: I didn't solve it. I thought I had a solution, but then I ran into the error message. I ran out of time to work on it, and had to leave it unsolved.